# Google WebApp Calculator

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to develop a basic Google Webapp calculator. I've got really tired of trying many scripts and watching Youtube videos for a couple of weeks, all I needs is a basic startup script where I can do some practices and gradually improve and learn on the script.

I've driven the plan on an image what I want, HTML containts (Price, Down Payment, Rate, Period and the answer will be Your monthly Pay) where I'm struggling is how to connect these to script and function in the google web app.

Can someone help me push start with this project? Thank you in Advance.

You can view the work so far I've accomplished here
Link https://script.google.com/a/autodirect.lk/d/1M9YYZIGXpOvmMZ9ESEh14HYfbshEoV9s9YqarYSg1qh8pEyV4G-Ki3rj/edit?usp=sharing

```js
function doGet(e) {
  Logger.log(e.parameter);
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("page");
}

function userClicked(name) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(
    "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mkbnIlDt6WGltQg6peKojBFPz0JwyjAkJGwTYbLYEmk/edit#gid=0"
  );
  
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  ws.appendRow([name, new Date()]);

  //Logger.log(name +" Clicked the Button");
}
```

HTML Code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top" />
    <style>
      .form-row {
        margin-bottom: 15px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <div class="form-row">
      <label>Price:</label><input type="text" id="price" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <label>Down Payment:</label><input type="text" id="DownPay" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <label>Period</label>
      <select id="app">
        <option>12</option>
        <option>24</option>
        <option>36</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <button id="btn">Run it</button>
    </div>

    <script>
      document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", doStuff);

      function doStuff() {
        var vprice = document.getElementById("price").value;
        google.script.run.userClicked(vprice);
        document.getElementById("price").value = "";
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the values of `price,downPayment,rate,period` and calculate `(price - downPayment) * rate / period`. And put the result value to the HTML.
- You want to add the inputted values and the calculated value to the Spreadsheet.
- You want to set "rate" as 10 % as the constant value in the script.

#### Modification points:

- In your script,

  - The input tag for "Rate" is not existing.
  - The tag for putting the result value is not existing.
  - The values from `downPayment` and `period` are not retrieved.
- In your case, I think that `google.script.run.userClicked()` and `document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = res` can be worked with the asynchronous process.
- The calculate of `(price - downPayment) * rate / period` is run at Javascript side.

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

HTML&Javascript side:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <style>
    .form-row {
      margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <div class="form-row">
    <label>Price:</label><input type="text" id="price">
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <label>Down Payment:</label><input type="text" id="DownPay">
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <label>Period</label>
    <select id="app">
      <option>12</option>
      <option>24</option>
      <option>36</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <button id="btn">Submit</button>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    Your Monthly Pay: <span id="res"></span>
  </div>

  <script>
    document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", doStuff);

    function doStuff() {
      const rate = 0.1;
      const vprice = document.getElementById("price").value;
      const downPayment = document.getElementById("DownPay").value;
      const period = document.getElementById("app").value;
      const res = (vprice - downPayment) * rate / period;
      document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = res;
      google.script.run.userClicked({
        vprice,
        downPayment,
        rate,
        period,
        res
      });
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Google Apps Script side:

In this case, `userClicked` was modified.

```
function doGet(e) {
  Logger.log(e.parameter);
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("page");
}

function userClicked({vprice, downPayment, rate, period, res}){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mkbnIlDt6WGltQg6peKojBFPz0JwyjAkJGwTYbLYEmk/edit#gid=0");
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  ws.appendRow([vprice, downPayment, rate, period, res, new Date()]);
}
```

- If you want to select the inputted values to Spreadsheet, please modify `[vprice, downPayment, rate, period, res, new Date()]`.

#### Note:

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please redeploy the Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to the Web Apps. Please be careful this.**

#### Reference:

- [Class google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

Comment: Wow.. you made it so easy :). Thanks, I need a little more help here, I do not want to display the Rate in the HTML body, but it should be in the script. What modification should i do?

Comment: @Muhammed Aadhil Thank you for replying. About `I do not want to display the Rate in the HTML body, but it should be in the script.`, in this case, I think that "rate" is required to be set as a value in the script. How about this? By the way, in your question, "rate" is displayed. So can I ask you about the detail of your goal? I would like to think of the solution by correctly understanding it. I apologize for this.

Comment: Yes, for example we can set 10%

Comment: @Muhammed Aadhil Thank you for replying. I updated the script. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: You are a Genius :)